# how to turn array into array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am working with an array of words for example:

const words = ["hello", "world", "how", "are", "you"]

How can I transform this into an array of objects:

```
const words1 = [ {0: "hello"}, {1: "world"},; {2: "how"}, {3: "are"}, {4: "you"} ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const words = ["hello", "world", "how", "are", "you"]

let op = words.map((value,key) => ({[key]: value}))

console.log(op)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `map` & return an object where key is the `index` and its value will be each item from the original array

```js
const words = ["hello", "world", "how", "are", "you"];
let result = words.map(function(item, index) {
  return {
    [index]: item
  }
});

console.log(result)
```

If you are trying with normal `for` loop then create an empty array and push object to it. Note the way `i` is placed inside `[]`

```js
const words = ["hello", "world", "how", "are", "you"];

let newArray = [];

for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
  newArray.push({
    [i]: words[i]
  })

}

console.log(newArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. Run the code and you'll see the result you're looking for printed out.

**NOTE:** This will work in older browsers and versions of JS. Solutions with { [index] : ... } will not.

```js
const words = ["hello", "world", "how", "are", "you"];
var obj;
for( let i=0; i < words.length; i++ )
{
  obj = {};
  obj[i] = words[i]
  words[i] = obj;
}
document.write( JSON.stringify( words ) );
```